# How to enable Coop in Rayman Origins?

Tags: rayman-origins

I have `Rayman Origins` on `Steam` but I didn't found the button to play with two players if I have two controllers connected.

The first works automatically, the second controller doesn't seems to activate the additional player.

What is the button to let the second player enter the game?

Answer (score 3):

Two 360 controllers is easy: With both 360 controllers switched on, go to **Options**  and click player 1, hit **reset**. Your first 2 controllers now work.

(Was able to do this successfully with 3-4 controllers also).

Answer (score 2):

When the second controller is connected and recognized by the device it should say:

> Player 2, press any button to join next to player 1.

On the pc version however you need to configure the controller before you can use it in the controls menu.

I have this myself game on the pc and wii and I play co-op a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think the second controller isn't detected by the game. See if both controllers show up in **Device manager**

Answer (score 1):

If it's an XBox controller, the button to join is "A".  The second player's icon should show up as a transparent icon next to player 1's in the top right of the screen when a second controller is detected.

Answer (score 1):

If you're like me and tried to sync 2nd controller via Steam Link, you have to connect controllers to PC first, wired (didn't test wireless). Once you setup the 2nd controller's controls in the options area, it should say "2-stick left , 2-stick right , etc" then you are good to go. Steam Link will now recognize the 2nd controller and can play wireless without problems.

Hope this saved someone else some time, took me a few to figure this out :P

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to configure all the buttons for the second player in the options and it worked then.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a wireless Xbox controller then you just have to make sure it's on before you start the game.

Answer (score 0):

Before you click play at the start of the game, go to 'options' then at the top left it says player 1 2 3 4. Click 2 (or however many people you are playing with),then go out of options and start the game.